# display stored procedure on my website (php, mssql)

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm whole new to stored procedures and mssql so i have no idea where to start with my code. I've tried to google/search around the forum but i dont understand the code.

Here is my scenario:
I've got the name of some stored procedures that i'm trying to display on my website using php. I have the name of the server(mssql), i've got the name of the database and i have a username and password to the server.

I've used Toad and tried the stored procedures(with success) and now im just trying to put together some code where i can display the results of the stored procedures on my website.

Firstly i've tried to just display the results of a stored procedure without parameters but nothing happens...

```
<?php

$server = "myServername";
$username = "myUsername";
$password = "myPassword";
$database = "myDatabase";

$connect = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Couldn't connect to SQL Server");
mssql_select_db($database, $connect) or die ("Couldn't open database");

$query = mssql_init("usp_ThisIsMyStoredProcedure", $connect);

$result = mssql_execute($query);

while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<li>" . $row[0] . "</li>";
}

?>
```

My website only displays: `-->" . $row[0] . ""; } ?> <--`

please feel free to come with tips on how i can restructure my code!

Comment: Is this just an excerpt or the complete code? Amongst other things it is missing HTML head,body and a ul/ol section for the li elements.

Comment: This is just the php, i have head, body etc outside of it

Answer (score 0):

(don't have enough reputation to comment your post so i post here).

Shouldn't you add the value you want ?

Like

```
echo "<li>" . $row[0]->{'id'} . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $row[0]->{'nickname'} . "</li>";
```

for example ...

Comment: Nope, $row[0] should be the first column of the row so should work. He could access the elements by names e.g. `$row['nickname']` but numerical indices should be fine